# Modificar registros a través de la relación con Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema: Tengo una tabla facturas y una tabla imágenes relacionadas de la siguiente forma factura hasOne imagen. Entonces me gustaría que por medio de esta relación al momento de crear una nueva factura poder modificar un registro imagen que ya esta guardado en la base de datos. Cambiando el campo factura_id por el ID de la factura creada.

Que debo hacer para que funcione?

Este es metodo store del FacturaController

```
 public function store(SaveFacturaRequest $request)
{



        $cliente_id = request('cliente_id');
        $rnc_cedula = request('rnc_cedula');
        $bienes = request('bienes');
        $ncf = request('ncf');
        $ncf_modificado = request('ncf_modificado');
        $date_comp = request('date_comp');
        $date_pago = request('date_pago');
        $tipo_bien = request('tipo_bien');
        $monto_servicios = request('monto_servicios');
        $monto_bienes = request('monto_bienes');
        $itebis_fact = request('itebis_fact');
        $itebis_retenido = request('itebis_retenido');
        $itebis_sujeto = request('itebis_sujeto');
        $itebis_costo = request('itebis_costo');
        $tipo_retencion = request('tipo_retencion');
        $monto_ret = request('monto_ret');
        $isr = request('isr');
        $impuesto_selec = request('impuesto_selec');
        $otras_tasas = request('otras_tasas');
        $propina = request('propina');
        $forma_pago = request('forma_pago');
        $operador = auth()->user()->name;

    Factura::create([
        'cliente_id'=> $cliente_id,
        'rnc_cedula'=> $rnc_cedula,
        'bienes'=> $bienes,
        'ncf'=> $ncf,
        'ncf_modificado'=> $ncf_modificado,
        'date_comp'=> $date_comp,
        'date_pago'=> $date_pago,
        'tipo_bien'=> $tipo_bien,
        'monto_servicios'=> $monto_servicios,
        'monto_bienes'=> $monto_bienes,
        'itebis_fact'=> $itebis_fact,
        'itebis_retenido'=> $itebis_retenido,
        'itebis_sujeto'=> $itebis_sujeto,
        'itebis_costo'=> $itebis_costo,
        'tipo_retencion'=> $tipo_retencion,
        'monto_ret'=> $monto_ret,
        'isr'=> $isr,
        'impuesto_selec'=> $impuesto_selec,
        'otras_tasas'=> $otras_tasas,
        'propina'=> $propina,
        'forma_pago'=> $forma_pago,
        'operador'=> $operador,
    ]);





    return redirect()->route('home.index');

}
```

Este es modelo de la factura:

```
    //Una factura tiene una sola imagen
    public function imagen(){
        return $this->hasOne(Imagen::class);
    }



    //Cada imagen pertenece a un unico usuario
    public function cliente(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class);
    }
```

}

Comment: Podrías agregar código de lo que haz intentado hasta el momento para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ya se lo agregue

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, gracias por editar tu pregunta, evita realizar varias veces la misma pregunta, realiza una pregunta en base a [ask], agregando lo que intentaste o investigaste. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio,saludos.

Comment: Gracias y disculpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes obtener el id que se acaba de insertar de la siguiente manera, por defecto ORM te devuelve el modelo completo insertado:

```
$data = Factura::create([
    'cliente_id'=> $cliente_id,
    'rnc_cedula'=> $rnc_cedula,
    'bienes'=> $bienes,
    'ncf'=> $ncf,
    'ncf_modificado'=> $ncf_modificado,
    'date_comp'=> $date_comp,
    'date_pago'=> $date_pago,
    'tipo_bien'=> $tipo_bien,
    'monto_servicios'=> $monto_servicios,
    'monto_bienes'=> $monto_bienes,
    'itebis_fact'=> $itebis_fact,
    'itebis_retenido'=> $itebis_retenido,
    'itebis_sujeto'=> $itebis_sujeto,
    'itebis_costo'=> $itebis_costo,
    'tipo_retencion'=> $tipo_retencion,
    'monto_ret'=> $monto_ret,
    'isr'=> $isr,
    'impuesto_selec'=> $impuesto_selec,
    'otras_tasas'=> $otras_tasas,
    'propina'=> $propina,
    'forma_pago'=> $forma_pago,
    'operador'=> $operador,
]);
```

en la variable `$data` esta almacenado tu id y puedes acceder a el de la siguiente manera `$id = $data->id`.

ahora debes ir a buscar el registro de la imagen que vas a actualizar (te suguiero que actualices tu pregunta con el modelo de tu tabla donde se guarda la imagen):

```
   $img = Image::find($id); // o el campo por que vas a filtrar
   $img->el_campo = $data->id;
   $img->save();
```

Comment: No hay necesidad hermano. Me resolviste el problemas. Un millón de gracias.

Comment: Marca la respuesta como valida, así tu ganarás reputación.
Saludos